# how to get firebase cloud messanging running on local host

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to get a simple firebase cloud message app, web, to run. The README of the sample app says:

```
1. On the command line run `firebase serve -p 8081` using the Firebase CLI tool to launch a local      server.
```

That gives the error

```
Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy/serve. If you are using PowerShell make sure you place quotes around any comma-separated lists (ex: --only "functions,firestore").
```

So I tried

```
firebase serve -p 8081 .
```

which returns

```
Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

How can I get a local web app that receives messages get running? Will similar troubles start again when hosting on firebase.

I am stuck. Firebase is an endless series of weird docu, weird results, all errors have been encountered by others and there are lon long threads on any of them.